# Euclidean direction

Tags: qgis, direction

i'm trying to calculate the euclidean direction, in ArcGIS its very easy using the [Euclidean Direction tool of Spatial Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001n000000) but in QGIS i don't find how to do it.

Any tips for this in free software?

Comment: Link goes to Euclidean Direction, not Distance. Which one do you need?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to create an XYZ text file compliant with GDAL XYZ http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html which can be viewed as points or raster, calculate the distances as point features and then use GDAL_Translate to convert to another (better) image format.

Comment: Sorry, is euclidean direction.

Comment: Thanks Michael, modify the XYZ text with a spreadsheet, but I had to put several conditions. Would be excellent if there is any especial plugin for this.

Answer (score 1):

- Vector->Analysis Tools->Distance Matrix
- Calculate just the nearest point
- Join the two x/y pairs to your output file
- The rest is just basic math in a right triangle

Comment: Solve them with an XYZ text, but thanks for your time.