# Why this pyqgis code cause crash dump in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, distance, direction

In ArcGIS there is gp.EucDirection to calculate Euclidean allocation, distance, and direction around a point, Is there equivalent function in pyqgis or gdal?

I wrote a script with help of [gene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2581/gene) and [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) to create Euclidean direction raster in pyqgis, this script is ok when raster file is small, but when I want to use it in a large area (for example 10000*7000 pixel) it causes crash dump and close QGIS, Is there a solution for this problem?
link of script: [Euclidean Direction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178464/65799)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Euclidean direction in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139099/euclidean-direction)?

Comment: Sorry It's not solution.